# Shared folder password is incorrect

Tags: windows-10, passwords, shared-folders

Logged in as user `nx11118...` on a Windows 10 machine with local ip address 192.168.0.107 and shared `OsImages` folder:

[image]

[image]

on some other Windows 10 machine opened file explorer, typed `\\192.168.0.107\OsImages`, pressed Enter, entered user name and password:

[image]

But got "The user name or password is incorrect".

What can be wrong? Does `nx11118...` user has enough permissions?

And it is not clear why does it ask for the credentials because I logged in with the same user `nx11118...`.

Diagnostics display this:

[image]

**EDIT1:**

I was able to share the folder with another user:

[image]

but still it is not clear why user `nx11118...` works.

**EDIT1:**

Tried IP\user:

[image]

but with no success.

**EDIT2:**

Tried also with machine name:

[image]

[image]

and still without success.

Comment: Your are attempting to authenticate the user from one machine connected n another machine. Even if the username is identical, you have to specify the machine name the username belongs to, in order to authenticate as that user. Try specifying the machine name along with the username using the appropriate syntax

Comment: @Ramhound I am not sure if the syntax is appropriate, but I tried IP\use with no success, see EDIT1.

Comment: I indicated the machine name your on, the machine name of one of the machines, is in your screenshot. The IP address isn’t the machine name

Comment: @Ramhound tried also with machine name, see EDIT2, still without success.